# A counterexample for $\operatorname{Ass}(M_1+M_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

$\newcommand{\Ass}{\operatorname{Ass}}$
Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Suppose $M=M_{1}+M_{2}$, then we have $\Ass(M)\supset  \Ass(M_{1})\cup \Ass(M_{2})$. What is an example when  $\Ass(M)\supsetneqq  \Ass(M_{1})\cup \Ass(M_{2})$?

Comment: $Ass(M)$. What a nice notation...

Comment: @julien: I love that notation myself. Very visual.

Comment: @Alex: Do you by any chance have the conditions $M$ is a finite $A$-module for a Noetherian ring $A$? (It is still false and my example in first comment still works.)

Comment: @user1, I think there is a condition $A$ is Noetherian. thanks.